# Miranda's book Lemma 1.3 pag. 58

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I show that, given $X_A$ and $X_B$ two conics in $\mathbb{P}^{2}(\mathbb{C})$, the map $T: X_A \mapsto X_B$ is holomorphic, where $B=T^{t}AT$ is the symmetric matrix defining the equation of the conic $X_B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $T$ is non-singular, the map $T:\mathbb{P}^2\to\mathbb{P}^2$ is holomorphic. To see this, look at it in local coordinates. Then the restriction of a holomorphic map to a subvariety is also holomorphic.